# How to prevent additional page requests after response sent

Tags: session, symfony, redirect, request, listener

I have configured a listener on kernel.request which sets a new response with redirect when the session time has reached a certain value. The listener works fine and redirects to a certain page, on the next request, after the session has ended. But my problem is on the page I have many links and if I press multiple times the same link, the initial request with the redirect is cancelled/stopped and a new request is made with the last link pressed and so it passes my redirect even though the session has ended and is destroyed. So, my question is how to prevent additional requests/link presses after the firs request is made?
Here is my code:

```
    public function onKernelRequestSession(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $route = $request->get('_route');
    $session = $request->getSession();
    if ((false === strpos($route, '_wdt')) && ($route != null)) {
        $session->start();
        $time = time() - $session->getMetadataBag()->getCreated();
        if ($route != 'main_route_for_idle_page') {
            if (!$session->get("active") && $route == 'main_route_for_site_pages') {
                $session->invalidate();
                $session->set("active", "1");
            } else {
                if ($time >= $this->sessionTime) {
                    $session->clear();
                    $session->invalidate();
                    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('main_route_for_idle_page')));
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($session->get("activ")) {
                $session->clear();
                $session->invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thak you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Idea #1: Simple incremental counter

- Each request sends sequence number as param which is being verified as expected at the server.
- Server increments the number and sends it back via response
- the new number is used in future requests

Basically, if server expects the SEQUENCE number to be `2` and client sends `1` the request is to be rejected.

### Idea #2: Unique hash each time

Similar to the idea above, but uses unique hashes to eliminate predictive nature of incremental sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas but I resolved it using Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue using JQuery: when a link was pressed I disabled the other ones and so only one request is made from the page:

```
var isClicked = false;
$(".menu-link").click(function(e) {
  if(!isClicked) {
      isClicked = true;
  } else {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Thanks.